# Can't register virtual US number with whatsapp business

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, voip

I used to use a virtual US number for registering and using WhatsApp Business (for people i don't trust and don't want to give my personal number) But now whenever I try to register a new virtual number, it says it's an invalid number for USA. I have tried 2ndLine, text+ and few more apps.. Can anyone explain what's happening and provide a solution if possible..
Thanks in advance

Comment: I use a Google voice number for WhatsApp business without any problems and i know others that do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.. Whatsapp business recently changed a few things.. But as far as ive tested it.. some virtual numbers still work from 2nd line and textnow(both are from same company ig). I mean 1 in 50 would work. Just give it a try!

Comment: yeah.. i did the same thing! and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Yes most virtual numbers have such restrictions, however you have a higher success rate if you use voice for verification instead of SMS, you cant even setup voicemail recording to retrieve the call playback.

If this fails get other similar virtual number provider like [TalkU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.talkyou.app.im&hl=en), you get credits by watching some ads, but the advantage is that you get to keep the number for the duration you're subscribing with credits (which you get from watching ads=free)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I got a virtual number form https://receive-sms-online.info and it worked!